# wordpress add multiple checkbox to database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem on how to insert multiple checkbox in wordpress $wpdb. please help me or any resources that I can learn. Thank you very much

```
   <div class="form-group">
    <ul class = "arrangement">
        <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "meal_arrangement[]"  value="Drinking Water">Drinking Water</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "meal_arrangement[]"  value="Snack">Snack</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "meal_arrangement[]"  value="Lunch">Lunch</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name = "meal_arrangement[]"  value="Dinner">Dinner</label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

this is my ajax

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){

 var dataform  =  $('#v_form').serialize();
 var checkValues =  $('input[name="meal_arrangement[]"]:checked').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_params.ajax_url,
            data: {"action": "data", 
                    "meal_arrangement":checkValues,
             },
               success: function(data){
               console.log('inserted');
           alert('ok');
        }
    });  
 });
```

my wordpress function:

```
  $table_client_event_meal = $wpdb->prefix."spaces_client_event_meal";
                 $meal_arrangement = sanitize_text_field($_POST["meal_arrangement"]);

                 $result2 =  $wpdb->insert( $table_client_event_meal, 
                    array( 
                      'meal_arrangement'=>$meal_arrangement,
                   )
                 );
```

Comment: did u checked `print_r($_POST)` in wordpress function?

Comment: yes the result is  [meal_arrangement] => Array ( [0] => Lunch [1] => Dinner )  i believe in $wpdb->insert() needs to have foreach.

Comment: and what are u getting in `var_dump($meal_arrangement);`

Comment: i get this for vardump -array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Snack" [1]=> string(5) "Lunch" }

Comment: i dont think, this array will insert. do u want to insert Snack and Lunch as comma seperated?

Comment: my goal is to insert this two strings to my table meal_arrangement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125569/discussion-between-devpro-and-coolshox).

Answer (score 1):

Hi All i get the solution by adding for loop condition in my wordpress function:

```
                 $meal_arrangement = $_POST["meal_arrangement"];
                 $count = count($meal_arrangement);   
                 for ( $i=0; $i < $count; $i++ ){

                 $result2 =  $wpdb->insert( $table_client_event_meal, 
                    array( 
                      'meal_arrangement'=>$meal_arrangement[$i],
                   )
                 );
               }
```